# Oracle SQL delete, insert records, keeping fixed quantity of rows ordered by date

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, union

As the title says, I'm trying to delete & insert records to an Historical Table.

The Historical **tbl_b** has to receive records from a **tbl_a**, filtered by the column *val_id*; but there is a limit of records per each *val_id*, also it must keep only the most recent ones per *val_id*.

###### TBL_A

- It has columns ***id_val***, ***reg_date***, ***flag***
- it has up to date records (constantly, records are inserted on this table).
- only records with *flag=1* should be inserted on TBL_B.
- records are deleted by another scheduled process.

| val_id | reg_date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 2022-10-20 23:00:00 | 1 |
| 22 | 2022-10-20 22:00:01 | 0 |
| 22 | 2022-10-20 22:00:02 | 1 |
| 11 | 2022-10-20 21:00:01 | 1 |
| 11 | 2022-10-20 21:00:02 | 1 |
| 11 | 2022-10-20 21:00:03 | 1 |

###### TBL_B:

- It has columns ***id_val***, ***reg_date***
- it should store 2 records per ***id_val*** and the most recent ones (order by ***reg_date***).
- it's partitioned monthly, this table will store 150 Million records aprox.

| val_id | reg_date |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 2022-10-19 11:00:01 |
| 11 | 2022-10-19 11:00:02 |
| 22 | 2022-10-19 12:00:01 |
| 22 | 2022-10-19 12:00:02 |

###### Desired Result on TBL_B:

| val_id | reg_date |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 2022-10-20 21:00:02 |
| 11 | 2022-10-20 21:00:03 |
| 22 | 2022-10-19 12:00:02 |
| 22 | 2022-10-20 22:00:02 |
| 33 | 2022-10-20 23:00:00 |

To approach this, I'm trying to do it in 2 steps:

1. first delete records from TBL_B, if it's necessary.
2. then insert records from TBL_A, since they are always the most recent ones.

But at this moment I'm stuck trying to filter the records that should be deleted from TBL_B.

Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73271c/1

```
DELETE FROM tbl_b where rowid in (
SELECT
  rowid
FROM (SELECT
  m.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY id_val
  ORDER BY
  reg_date DESC
  ) AS rownumb
FROM (SELECT
  h.*
FROM tbl_b h
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  tbl_a.*,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  PARTITION BY id_val
  ORDER BY
  reg_date DESC
  ) AS seqnum
FROM tbl_a
WHERE flag = 1) f
WHERE f.seqnum <= 2) t
  ON t.id_val = h.id_val) m) n
WHERE n.rownumb > 2
);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need TBL_B? Wouldn't a **view** - based on TBL_A - which returns only two most recent rows do the job?

Comment: @Littlefoot I've updated the info on the OP. We need TBL_B because records are constantly deleted from TBL_A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'd rather do it just the opposite of what you wanted: I'd insert rows first, and delete superfluous rows next. Why? Because - if you're deleting rows first, you have to calculate how many rows to leave in `TBL_B` so that you'd insert the right number of rows from `TBL_A` so that `TBL_B` always contains up to 2 most recent rows. That's just too complex.

Also, indexes you currently have on these tables are kind of *wrong*; I'd index `id_val` and `reg_date` in both tables; indexing `flag` (at the first sight, unless there are *many* flags, not just e.g. 0 and 1) won't help much.

OK, here's my suggestion: initial `TBL_B` table contents:

```
SQL> select * from tbl_b order by id_val, reg_date;

ID_VAL REG_DATE
------ -------------------
11     2022-10-19 11:00:01
11     2022-10-19 11:00:02
22     2022-10-19 12:00:01
22     2022-10-19 12:00:02

SQL>
```

Insert first: fetch two most recent rows per `id_val` - that's the maximum rows you'd have if there are no rows in `TBL_B` at all:

```
SQL>     insert into tbl_b (id_val, reg_date)
  2        with temp as
  3          (select id_val,
  4                  reg_date,
  5                  rank() over (partition by id_val order by reg_date desc) rnk
  6           from tbl_a
  7           where flag = 1
  8          )
  9        select t.id_val, t.reg_date
 10        from temp t
 11        where t.rnk <= 2;

4 rows created.
```

Delete superfluous rows:

```
SQL> delete from tbl_b a
  2  where exists
  3         (select null
  4          from (select b.id_val,
  5                       b.reg_date,
  6                       rank() over (partition by b.id_val order by b.reg_date desc) rnk
  7                from tbl_b b
  8               ) x
  9          where x.id_val = a.id_val
 10            and x.reg_date = a.reg_date
 11            and x.rnk > 2
 12         );

3 rows deleted.
```

The final result:

```
SQL> select * from tbl_b order by id_val, reg_date;

ID_VAL REG_DATE
------ -------------------
11     2022-10-20 11:00:02
11     2022-10-20 11:00:03
22     2022-10-19 12:00:02
22     2022-10-20 22:00:02
33     2022-10-20 23:00:00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to use analytic functions `DENSE_RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` in your SQL query in order to resolve the task:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_b 
 WHERE reg_date in (SELECT reg_date 
                      FROM (SELECT t.*
                                 , dense_rank() over (order by trunc(reg_date) desc) as d_rank
                                 , row_number() over (PARTITION BY TRUNC(REG_DATE) order by reg_date DESC) as r_num
                             
                              FROM tbl_b t)
                     WHERE d_rank = 2 and r_num <> 1);
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m6nMXfIr)

**Note:** `DELETE` has to run after insert into the records from TBL_A (the most recent ones)

It would be good idea - `CREATE TRIGGER AFTER INSERT ON tbl_b` to perform `DELETE`

Comment: thank you for you help. After executing the query, tbl_b has more records than it should, it should have only 2 records ( the most recent ones) per id_val.